# Resolve grammar: function call without parentheses VS an expression

Tags: parsing, context-free-grammar

I'm making a language for fun. I'd like to have function calls without parentheses too (like in ruby) so they would be just optional. So the grammar would look something like:

```
expression:
    ... other expressions
    | <a function call with parentheses>
    | IDENTIFIER expression_list   -> function call without parentheses
    ;
expression_list:
    expression_list COMMA expression
    | expression
    ;
```

My problem is that I of course have variables and expressions like addition, unary and so on. So if I have this:

```
x - y
```

This could either mean a function call x with parameter -y or a simple subtraction.

I'd like this to be a subtraction. I'd only want this to be a function call if there's no other possibility, for example:

```
x y
```

There are no operators between so this could only be a function call.

Is there no other way to resolve this but to track symbols while parsing? I just don't see any solution based on pure grammar modification. If there isn't a grammar-only solution then how could I discard a rule and tell bison to match with another one?

I'm using bison as my parser generator by the way.

Edit: my terminal precedence:

```
%left COMMA
  .....
%left PLUS MINUS
  ... others, like multiply
%left LPAR RPAR
```

Edit 2:

So I've realized all the problems. I  need backtracking somehow. How could I do something like this:

```
IDENT exp_list { if ($1 is not defined) { back_and_choose_another_rule(); } }
```

with bison?

Comment: What do *you* think `x - y` should mean? If you have an intended operator precedence, then you could probably encode that using precedence rules in bison.

Comment: @templatetypedef As far as I know I can only give the terminals precedence rules. I'll edit my post.

Comment: @templatetypedef I forgot to clarify my answer, did that too. If I could tell bison within the rule to match another rule instead that would be perfect too.

Comment: `I'd only want this to be a function call if there's no other possibility` - what if the user really _does_ want to call function `x` with an argument of `- y`?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Geez... true. How does ruby resolve this? I guess it tracks symbols while parsing. Then how do I tell bison to cancel the current rule?
Like: IDENTIFIER expression_list { if ($1 is not a defined function) { cancel_rule_and_try_sthg_else(); } }